# View to display the comments of the curent user nodes

Tags: views, comments

Please how to create a simple view to display the comments of the curent user nodes, only comments,
Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

When you add a new view (/admin/structure/views/add), you have the possibility to select Comments.
It will list all comments.

Then you need to set a Contextual Filter and a Relation in order to get the comments of the current logged in user.

Comment: Thank you Matt, i don't want  comments of curent user, but comments created by others (..of nodes created by curent user)

Comment: Then you will need to play around with the Relations: create a relation with your current logged in user, to link to all the nodes he created. Then list all comments of these nodes, and exclude those created by your user with a filter.